# Tag synonym request [gba] & [gameboy-advance] → [game-boy-advance]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I want to request that [gba](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gba) & [gameboy-advance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameboy-advance) be made synonyms for [game-boy-advance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy-advance). I tried doing it myself, but I don't have enough rep there to do it myself.

Comment: [gameboy-advance] should be the top-level tag.

Comment: Mods: Both or neither of this and [`[gameboy] -> [game-boy]`](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2960/tag-synonym-request-gameboy-game-boy) should be done for consistency.  @GnomeSlice "Game Boy", not "GameBoy", is the official name as noted in the other post.

Answer (score 2):

Thy tags be synonymized. Rejoiceth!

Comment: Yays! \10chars.